# Instantiate using Windsor's factory

Tags: naming-conventions, castle-windsor

Below's code is working fine, and successfully create an instance for class **DummyComponnent**.
But the problem arises when i had changed the factory method name `CreatDummyComponnent()` 
to `GetDummyComponnent()` or anything else except **Creat** as the beginning of method name, say `AnyThingComponent` throws an exception. is there any specify naming rule for factory methods ?

```
using System;
using Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.Windsor;

namespace AsFactoryImplementation
{
    public interface IDummyComponnentFactory
    {
        IDummyComponnent CreatDummyComponnent();
//        void Relese(IDummyComponnent factory);
    }

    public interface IDummyComponnent
    {
        void Show();
    }

    public class DummyComponnent:IDummyComponnent
    {
        public DummyComponnent()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("we are working here");
        }
        public void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("just testing this for better performance");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new WindsorContainer();
            container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

            container.Register(Component.For<IDummyComponnent>().ImplementedBy<DummyComponnent>().Named("FirstConnection"),
                Component.For<IDummyComponnentFactory>().AsFactory());

            var val = container.Resolve<IDummyComponnentFactory>();
            var iDummy = val.CreatDummyComponnent();
            iDummy.Show();
                Console.WriteLine("OK its done ");
                Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use anything for starting the method names on the Factory, except for starting with Get.

If you start with Get it will try to resolve the component by name instead of by interface.
So what would work in your example is:

var iDummy = val.GetFirstConnection();

Good luck,

Marwijn.

Comment: i am curious that as in my example, i had tried to resolve component by interface, then using like this `var iDummy = val.GetFirstConnection();` will work ?